# Display kendo dropdownlist popup when clicking on image

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to click on an icon/image and then get a kendo dropdown list to appear below he icon/image?

(In other words I only want do use the popup of a dropdownlist, I would like the input editor to be hidden and replace it with an image, when the user clicks the image the popup dropdownlist should appear)

The closest I have come to a solution is to hide the input element

```
<div style="display:none;"> <input id="dropdownlist"/> </div>
```

And when image/icons is clicked I open kendo dropdownlist popup

```
$("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").open();
```

The problem with this is that the popup menu is displayed in the top left corner, I have not found a way to make the popup appear below icon/image.

Comment: which version of kendo you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little snippet of code that might suite your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
    <input id="dropdownlist" style="height: 100px;" />
  </div>

  <img src="https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/gallery/1778374_200x130.png" style="height: 100px; position: absolute;" onclick="$('#dropdownlist').data('kendoDropDownList').open()" />
<script>
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  index: 1
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the image height and the dropdown height should be the same.